# Proper disposing of nested native collections

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have following structs:

```cs
public struct BasicIndividualStruct
{
  public void Dispose()
  {
    path.Dispose();
  }

  public float fitness;
  public UnsafeList<float2> path;
}

public struct NativeBasicPopulation
{
  public void Dispose()
  {
    foreach(var individual in _population)
    {
      individual.Dispose();
    }
    _population.Dispose();
  }

  public NativeArray<BasicIndividualStruct> _population;
}
```

I am creating it like this:

```cs
    var population = new NativeArray<BasicIndividualStruct>(50, Allocator.TempJob);
    for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
    {
      var element = population[i];
      element.path = new Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.UnsafeList<Unity.Mathematics.float2>(10, Allocator.TempJob);
      element.path.Resize(10);
      element.fitness = 0;
      population[i] = element;
    } 
    var pop = new NativeBasicPopulation()
    {
      _population = population
    };
```

My question is - how to properly dispose it after the job ends?

Is my `_population` inside `NativeBasicPopulation` just copy of local `pop` variable, therefore I need to call `Dispose` on `pop` right away?

Will the loop inside `NativeBasicPopulation::Dispose` actually work? Because from my understanding, `individual` in given loop is just a copy of an element inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/job-system-copy-nativecontainer.html) says:

> Native containers are value types, which means that when they’re assigned to a variable, Unity copies the NativeContainer structure, which contains pointers to where the native container’s data is stored, including its AtomicSafetyHandle. **It doesn’t copy the entire contents of the NativeContainer**.

> This scenario means that there might be multiple copies of a NativeContainer structure which all reference the same region of memory.

> If a NativeContainer is disposed of, all the copies of the NativeContainer structure must recognize that the original NativeContainer is invalid.

In summary, you can assign a `NativeContainer` instance to multiple variables, but you only need to call `Dispose` on one of them. So for your problem, you don't need to dispose `pop` immediately, but should dispose the object you saved after the job ends.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about 
`foreach(var individual in _population){individual.Dispose();}` 
tough? Is `individual` just a copy of my struct member that has unrelated `UnsafelList`?

Comment: The member is a pointer, so it is a copy but all the copies are related.